# CSVLogger does not work for model.evaluate process for keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to log the evaluate result to a file with tensorflow 2.0 (keras). I use the callback method. It works well for model.fit but seems not work for model.evaluate.
this is my code:

```
csv_logger = CSVLogger(logfile, append=True, separator=';')
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=50, callbacks=[csv_logger]) // works
model.evaluate(test_dataset, callbacks=[csv_logger]) // not work
```

Am I do the wrong way to log evaluate result to file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `CSVLogger` implements callback methods only for training. 
For evaluate, `on_test_begin()`, `on_test_batch_begin()`, `on_test_batch_end()` and `on_test_end()` callback methods are invoked by the keras training module which are not implemented by CSVLogger and hence no csv files are created when used with model.evaluate().

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.0.0-alpha0/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1514

A custom CSV callback could be implemented like this:

```
class MyCSVLogger(Callback):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        print(filename)

    def on_test_begin(self, logs=None):
        # open csv file
        print('test begin')

    def on_test_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        pass

    def on_test_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        # write the contents of the dictionary logs to csv file
        # sample content of logs {'batch': 0, 'size': 2, 'loss': -0.0, 'accuracy': 1.0}
        print(logs)

    def on_test_end(self, logs=None):
        # close csv file
        print('test end')

csv_logger = MyCSVLogger('abc.csv')
model.evaluate(X_eval,y_eval, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just here to add my 2 cents to Manoj Mohan's great answer. It is somewhat hacky, but I found that adding the following lines of code makes it work for TF2.1:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
CSVLogger.on_test_begin = CSVLogger.on_train_begin
CSVLogger.on_test_batch_end = CSVLogger.on_epoch_end
CSVLogger.on_test_end = CSVLogger.on_train_end
```

Basically it just adds test-case functions to the CSVLogger class that are identical to those of the train-case functions. The only caveat is that it will also create an epoch column in your CSV file. The saved statistics are from the batches though